# FormulaR1C1 reading False

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a userform in excel which is adding data to the last row of a table. in column 14 of the last row I am wanting excel to display the formula however it is always reading false. If I take out the lastrow and do this as a separate entity alone then this works perfectly.

In the example it should be giving the answer 26.5 * 2 which should of course yield 53, not FALSE since RC[-1] is blank.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Primary Data")

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", Searchorder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

ws.Cells(iRow, 14).Value = FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""",RC[-2]*RC[-3],RC[-2]*RC[-3]*(1-RC[-1]))"

End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me with this conundrum.

Comment: Tim's answer will fix the problem, but the reason **why** your code is failing is because your are performing the logical expression `FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""",RC[-2]*RC[-3],RC[-2]*RC[-3]*(1-RC[-1]))"` which, because the variable `FormulaR1C1` has never been declared or assigned a value, is equivalent to `"" = "=IF(RC[-1]="""",RC[-2]*RC[-3],RC[-2]*RC[-3]*(1-RC[-1]))"` which is obviously `False`, and then you are assigning that to the cell.  You can avoid these problems by using `Option Explicit` as the first line of each code module.  That would tell you that `FormulaR1C1` is undeclared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do `ws.Cells(iRow, 14).Value = FormulaR1C1` because you're not setting a value, use `ws.Cells(iRow, 14).FormulaR1C1 =`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Primary Data")

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", Searchorder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

ws.Cells(iRow, 14).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""",RC[-2]*RC[-3],RC[-2]*RC[-3]*(1-RC[-1]))"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, absolutely yes that makes sense. Has worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Another option, which will work if the values in column "K", "L" and "M" already exist before running this code is:

```
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = ws.Cells(iRow, 14)
Rng.Value = IIf(Rng.Offset(, -1) = "", _
                    Rng.Offset(, -2) * Rng.Offset(, -3), _
                    Rng.Offset(, -2) * Rng.Offset(, -3) * (1 - Rng.Offset(, -1)))
```

Comment: Dunno why I'm feeling attracted these days to drop `Offset` and use notation like `IIf(Rng(,0) = "", Rng(, -1) * Rng(, -2),... ` ;)

Comment: @A.S.H me too, that's why I've added this solution ;)

Comment: (may be a little chatty, TLDR) a lot of shortcuts in VBA code were dropped by "common practice" for sake of making it as compatible as possible to `VB.net`. Among them the `[ ]` notation, the implicit `.Value`, etc. That was at a time when everyone was thinking that VB.net *"will definitely replace VB6 and VBA"*. I have a big question mark on these motivations today...

Comment: just spent another 0.5 hour here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067788/change-event-procedure-for-moving-pivot-chart/45070846#45070846 , now I can go shave ;)