# _Change event procedure for moving Pivot Chart

Tags: vba, excel

What is true with _Change sheet's event?
I have bellow problem in _Change event procedure while this code works in other subroutines truly.

This macro wrote for moving Pivot Chart.

Microsoft Excel will close and encounter this error:
Microsoft Excel has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience. and will close.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("sheet1").PivotTables("pvtReport").TableRange2.Cut
Cells(Sheets("sheet1").ListObjects("tblReport").Range.Rows.Count + 2, 13).Select
Sheets("sheet1").Paste
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PvtReport").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Cells(Selection.Row + 2, Selection.Column).Select

Sheets("sheet1").ChartObjects("InsuranceChart").Cut
Sheets("sheet1").Paste
End Sub
```

Please note that this code encounter error in `Sheets("sheet1").ChartObjects("InsuranceChart").Cut` line.

Comment: What is your intention with that and the next line, isn't it like picking something up and putting it back down?

Comment: I have a table in my sheet, so that's rows are extending. I want my PivotTable and Pivot Chart, stay at the end of the table. My code in line `Sheets("sheet1").ChartObjects("InsuranceChart").Cut` encounter MS Excel problem, in Worksheet_Change subroutine while this macro and that line are working correctly in my created subroutines, and Pivot table and Pivot chart will moving to the end of the table and end corner of that programmatically, so I need this act done when User add a table line and change a value in the sheet.

Comment: Can you explain your entire process , maybe I can offer a better simpler solution to what you are trying to achieve. For instance, if this `Worksheet_Change` event is in "sheet1" code module, you can remove all places where you use in your code "sheet1", since it's referenced as the `ActiveSheet` when using the ` Worksheet_Change`. Also, you have too many `Select`, which you don't really need.

Comment: @MGae2M have you tried my answer and code below ?

Comment: I'm at weekend and Saturday will go my office and try and check this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thank of friends guidance, I reached to suitable answer specially for Right to Left sheet:

Seems there were great different between `TableRange1.Left` and `ChartObject().Left` calculation.

In fact `TableRange1.Left` related to sheets `Direction`, and `ChartObject().Left` is not related, and calculate from left side of sheet.

The problem solved in code below with addition explanation after.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim ChartLeft, SheetWidth As Double

    SheetWidth = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells.Width

    ChartLeft = SheetWidth - _
    (Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("InsuranceChart").Width + _
    Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("pvtReport").TableRange1.Left)

    Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("InsuranceChart").Top = _
    Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("pvtReport").TableRange1.End(xlDown).Offset(2).Top
    Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("InsuranceChart").Left = ChartLeft

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

### Explanation:

We used sheet's width to calculate distance between left side of PivotChart from Left corner of WorkSheet, in the Right to Left sheet; from distance of Right corner of Pivot Table to Right side of WorkSheet.

Note that `TableRange1.Left` is distance of the Right corner of PivotTable from Right side of WorkSheet, (In Right to Left Worksheets directional) and `ChartObject().Left` is distance of Left corner of PivotChart from Left side of Worksheet (In both WorkSheets direction).

And because of relation between PivotChart position and PivotTable, that we want PivotChart position is functioned to respective PivotTable, thus calculate Left side of PivotTable from Right side of that, and its `Width` and WorkSheets width, then assign this value to left corner of PivotChart by `ChartObject().Left` property of PivotChart.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to keep only the basic in the `Worksheet_Change` event, and have the rest of the logic, objects and code in a `Sub` in a regular module.

In order to move the Pivot Chart, you can use the `Top` and `Left` properties of the `ChartObject`.

More explanations inside the code as comments.

***Worksheet_Change* Code (inside worksheet module)**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

MovePivotTable Target.Parent ' call the reugular Sub and pass the Worksheet object

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

***Sub MovePivotTable* (regular module)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MovePivotTable(ws As Worksheet)

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Dim TblReport As ListObject
Dim InsurChtObj As ChartObject

With ws
    ' set the Pivot Table object
    Set PvtTbl = .PivotTables("pvtReport")

    ' set the Table object (ListObject)
    Set TblReport = .ListObjects("tblReport")

    ' set the Pivot Table Chart object
    Set InsurChtObj = .ChartObjects("InsuranceChart")

    ' move the Pivot Table at the end of the Table Object
    PvtTbl.TableRange2.Cut Destination:=.Cells(TblReport.Range.Rows.Count + 2, 13)

    ' move the Pivot chart at the end of the Table
    InsurChtObj.Top = PvtTbl.TableRange1.End(xlDown).Offset(2).Top ' go to the bottom of the Pivot-Table range + 2 more rows
    InsurChtObj.Left = PvtTbl.TableRange1.Left
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: A problem at `InsurChtObj.Left = PvtTbl.TableRange1.Left` so PivotChart been hide. I checked the Left value by `Msgbox` and compare with corporate value of PivobTable. Result is: 884565.76 value for PivotChart and 843.75 is value of PivotTable. Thus PivotChart been hide after running last line of macro code.

Comment: I asked a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116548/whats-different-beetwin-left-property-in-chartobjects-and-tablerange) about the related issue about your answer.

Comment: Thank you for `Application.EnableEvents = False` code. This helped me in many problems issue. And whats the reason of your recommendation for keeping only basics in the `Worksheet_Change()` event?

Comment: @MGae2M  I don't like to put code that is not related to Worksheet events in a Worksheet module. Also, if in the future, you would want to use this in another sheet, then already have 90% of the code ready for you.

Comment: Of course. Whats meaning of "Related to Worksheet events"? And when we say a code is related to WorkSheet event?

Comment: Shai Rado, How is My answer?